# C - Truncate char* string argument

Tags: c, linux

I've been trying to do this simple task for a while now but can't get it to work properly as I'm not super familiar with pure C tricks.

Basically I have a function that get called by a block of code that I didn't write myself and can't edit.

```
int myMethod(char* str);
```

My task is to find the position of a substring in the char* and if found get the string from index 0 to index of the found substring and assign it to the original char* str.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
int myMethod(char* str)
{    
    int splitPos = strstr(str, "Pikachu") - str;
    char buffer[splitPos + 1];
    strncpy(buffer, str, splitPos);

    buffer[splitPos] = '\0';
    memcpy(str, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
}
```

And I get a SegFault at the last strcpy call. I tried changing it to the followings with the same result

- memmove(str, buffer, ...)
- strcpy(...)

Comment: The problem is with the string pointer passed into your function. The data is not modifiable. (And I'm ignoring the wrong number of parameters to strcpy in your code sample).

Comment: @StoryTeller: _The data is not modifiable._ How do you know that?

Comment: @KeineLust - It's either that or `splitPos` being crazy wrong. But then the illegal access is just as likely to happen sooner, and not just at the last line.

Comment: Are you sure that the substring is found correctly? You don't check for `NULL` from `strstr()`.

Comment: I removed most of the conditional logic. You can assume that the substring is always found and splitPos give the correct index.

Comment: Right. A [mcve] please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your function:

- you do not check the return value of `strstr` for success. Your code has undefined behavior if it fails to locate the substring.
- `strncpy` will not null terminate the destination string if the source is longer than `splitPos-1`, which it is. Do not use `strncpy`, it does not do what you think, it is very error prone for both the programmer and the reader. For your purpose, `memcpy` with the same arguments is equivalent and less problematic.
- `strlen(buffer)` is redundant, it evaluates to `splitPos`.
- You actually do not need a temporary buffer for your goal: truncating the string can be done by simply setting the start of the substring to `'\0'`.
- if the destination string is read-only, modifying it has undefined behavior, and might explain the observed segmentation fault.

Here is a simplified version:

```
int myMethod(char *str) {    
    char *p = strstr(str, "Pikachu");
    if (p != NULL) {
        *p = '\0';
    }
}
```

Conversely if you just need to manipulate the substring in further code in `myMethod`, you can make a copy to avoid the fateful attempt at modifying the original string:

```
int myMethod(char *str) {    
    char *p = strstr(str, "Pikachu");
    size_t len = p ? p - str : stren(str);
    char buffer[len + 1];
    memcpy(buffer, str, len);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    str = buffer;
    /* use `str` in this function */
}
```

Comment: Great answer, well explained.  Specifically, the `strstr(...) - str` itself will result in segmentation fault if string is not found, resulting in a pointer arithmetic with NULL.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick explanation ! I assumed too much about the output of strstr and holding the buffer was bad. I took your version, made a few little twists to make it fit in my original code and it works perfectly !

Modifying the original string was a must, basically this is code hooking and I wanted to modify the parameters before original method got called.

Comment: @codeforester: `strstr(...) - str` has undefined behavior if `strstr` returns `NULL`, but is very unlikely to cause a segmentation fault.  Allocating an automatic buffer with the resulting size definitely has undefined behavior **and** can explain the crash, copying to that buffer too.

Comment: On my Linux (Ubuntu) instance, it did.